# Error when compiling Linux kernel, please install syslinux/isolinux

Tags: linux, kernel, compile

I'm using Parrot OS to compile Linux kernel and I'm trying to make an ISO file, but when I run `make -j8 isoimage` I get this error:

```
  DESCEND  objtool
  CALL    scripts/atomic/check-atomics.sh
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#2)
  GENIMAGE arch/x86/boot/image.iso
Need an isolinux.bin file, please install syslinux/isolinux.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/boot/Makefile:149: isoimage] Error 1
make: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:264: isoimage] Error 2
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you can use https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=ISOLINUX#How_Can_I_Make_a_Bootable_CD_With_ISOLINUX.3F since it says to install it as such

Comment: Have you tried to do what it says? (_"please install syslinux/isolinux"_)

Comment: @gronostaj i google it, but i found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install syslinux isolinux
```

worked for me

I had the same problem